# Django: annotate Count with filter

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have "post" objects and a "post like" object with how many likes a post has received by which user:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    text     = models.CharField(max_length=500, default ='')
    user     = models.ForeignKey(User)

class PostLike(models.Model):
    user    = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post    = models.ForeignKey(Post)
```

I can select how many likes a post has received like this:

```
Post.objects.all().annotate(likes=Count('postlike'))
```

This roughly translates to:

```
SELECT p.*,
       Count(l.id) AS likes
    FROM post p, postlike l
    WHERE p.id = l.post_id
    GROUP BY (p.id)
```

It works. Now, how I can *filter* the `Count` aggregation by the current user? I'd like to retrieve not *all* the likes of the post, but all the likes *by the logged user*. The resulting SQL should be like:

```
SELECT p.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM postlike WHERE postlike.user_id = 1 AND postlike.post_id = p.id) AS likes
FROM post p, postlike l
WHERE p.id = l.post_id
GROUP BY (p.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly as clean, but you could use [`Case`/`When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)...

```
posts = Post.objects.all().annotate(likes=models.Count(
  models.Case(
    models.When(postlike__user_id=user.id, then=1),
    default=0,
    output_field=models.IntegerField(),
  )
))
```

And of course, you can always drop down to `.extra()` or even raw SQL when there's something you can't express via the Django ORM.

Answer (score 12):

Do you know that `Count` has a `filter` argument?

```
Post.objects.annotate(
    likes=Count('postlike', filter=Q(postlike__user=logged_in_user))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add filter first:

```
Post.objects.filter(postlike__user=request.user).annotate(likes=Count('postlike'))
```

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses):

> The filter precedes the annotation, so the filter constrains the objects considered when calculating the annotation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but this doesn't solve my problem. I don't want the posts liked by the user, I want ALL the posts and for each, eventually, the number of likes by the user. Post.objects.filter won't give me the full recordset of posts.